# MySQL single table static and dynamic pivot

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----------------------------------------+
|Name                | kode      | jum   |
+----------------------------------------+
| aman               |kode1      | 2     |
| aman               |kode2      | 1     |
| jhon               |kode1      | 4     |
| amir               |kode2      | 4     |
+--------------------+-----------+-------+
```

How can I make a view like this with MySQL?

```
                    kode1    kode2     count
aman                  2         1        3  
jhon                  0         4        4
amir                  0         4        4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a form of a "pivot", you should use that search term to find other options.

You can try something like this:

```
select
     name
   , sum(case when kode = 'kode1' then jum else 0 end) as 'kode1'
   , sum(case when kode = 'kode2' then jum else 0 end) as 'kode2'
   , sum(jum) as count
from foo
group by name;
```

(assuming your example view has an error for `jhon`)

Example:

```
mysql> select * from foo;
+------+-------+------+
| name | kode  | jum  |
+------+-------+------+
| aman | kode1 |    2 |
| aman | kode2 |    1 |
| jhon | kode1 |    4 |
| amir | kode2 |    4 |
+------+-------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select
    ->      name
    ->    , sum(case when kode = 'kode1' then jum else 0 end) as 'kode1'
    ->    , sum(case when kode = 'kode2' then jum else 0 end) as 'kode2'
    ->    , sum(jum) as count
    -> from foo
    -> group by name;
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| name | kode1 | kode2 | count |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| aman |     2 |     1 |     3 |
| amir |     0 |     4 |     4 |
| jhon |     4 |     0 |     4 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 11):

If you have a known number of columns, then you can use a static version similar to the other answer. But if you have an unknown number then you can use a [prepared statement](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) similar to this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when kode = ''',
      kode,
      ''' then jum else 0 end) AS ',
      kode
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yourtable;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT name, ', @sql, ', sum(jum) as `count`
                  FROM yourtable 
                  GROUP BY name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13d5e/3)

Result is the same:

```
| NAME | KODE1 | KODE2 | COUNT |
--------------------------------
| aman |     2 |     1 |     3 |
| amir |     0 |     4 |     4 |
| jhon |     4 |     0 |     4 |
```

Comment: A stored proc to do this work:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Answer (score 8):

To convert row to column you need to use `CASE` statement. And to get count for individual `kode` you need to use `SUM` function like this one:

```
SELECT NAME,
       SUM(CASE kode WHEN 'kode1' THEN jum ELSE 0 END) AS kode1
      ,SUM(CASE kode WHEN 'kode2' THEN jum ELSE 0 END) AS kode2
      ,SUM(jum) AS `Count`
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Name
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b467/9)