# Place multiple related records into single table with extra fields

Tags: sql-server

I have these two tables below with a Key field of BOVA which forms a many to one relationship.

I am trying to join these 2 tables but create additional fields to house the numerous STATUS fields.  There can be 1 or up to 72 different STATUS values. This is the basis of the One to Many

What I am trying to get to is something like this after the JOIN

There is a mistake in the image below.... 010031 for the BOVA ID should be 010002

[image]

Can this be done and if so are there any examples around that could show me the way?

Table1

[image]

Table2

[image]

Comment: I was trying this but cannot get this to work...

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270402/one-to-many-relationship-query-result-in-a-single-row-and-dynamic-multiple-colum

Comment: How do you decide which value in the `STATUS` column goes into which ordered `Status#` column in the final results?...is it in ascending numerical order? Does every `BOVA` always have 72 `STATUS` values?

Answer (score 0):

So I think this will accomplish what you need, with a few manipulations of your tables via CTEs:

```
WITH _Table2Sorted AS -- Sorts the STATUS column by value ascending with SortId "buckets" to later be transposed on with a pivot
(
    SELECT
        BOVA,
        [STATUS],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BOVA ORDER BY [STATUS]) AS SortId
    FROM Table2
),
_Table2Pivoted AS -- Pivots the values of the STATUS column into each respective ordered Status# column, for each BOVA
(
    SELECT 
        PT.BOVA,
        MAX(PT.[1]) AS Status1, -- Aggregate functions needed on these fields because of the GROUP BY clause, but doesn't change the values here because every other row has NULL
        MAX(PT.[2]) AS Status2,
        MAX(PT.[3]) AS Status3,
        MAX(PT.[4]) AS Status4,
        MAX(PT.[5]) AS Status5,
        MAX(PT.[6]) AS Status6,
        MAX(PT.[7]) AS Status7
        -- You'll need to fill in the remaining columns for each status, up to Status72
    FROM _Table2Sorted
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([STATUS]) FOR SortId IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]) -- You'll need to fill in the remaining columns for each status, up to [72]
    ) AS PT
    GROUP BY PT.BOVA -- Grouping needed to collapse all the pivoted rows into a single row per BOVA
)

-- Final results joined back to Table1 to get additional meta-data (PHYLUM, CLASS, etc)
SELECT
    T2.BOVA,
    T2.[Status1],
    T2.[Status2],
    T2.[Status3],
    T2.[Status4],
    T2.[Status5],
    T2.[Status6],
    T2.[Status7],
    -- Fill in the other Status# columns up to Status72
    T1.PHYLUM,
    T1.CLASS
FROM _Table2Pivoted AS T2
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS T1
    ON T2.BOVA = T1.BOVA
```

Details are in the comments, but to summarize the steps:

1. First this uses a window function (`ROW_NUMBER()`) to generate a list of `SortId`s to be used as buckets when we pivot in the next step.
2. Then pivot the data into columns for each `SortId` we generated in the previous step, putting the value of `STATUS` into each respective `SortId` bucket.
3. The output of the `PIVOT` results in multiple rows per BOVA (1 for each `STATUS` value, and `NULL` in each other column) so we must use `GROUP BY` to collapse the rows into a single row per `BOVA`.
4. Finally select the results of the pivoted CTE and join them to `Table1` to get the additional meta-data needed such as `PHYLUM` and `CLASS`.

There might be a more efficient way to accomplish your goal, but this seems pretty decent.

Example output with a subset of sample data you provided:
[image: Results]

*Note my comments in the code where you'll need to fill in the other `Status#` columns I left out (for simplicity) up to `Status72`.

Comment: First off thank you for your reply.  I am reviewing this now to see if I fully understand...
OK so this reads all the Status values and that is what I specified ... Thinking a bit further... Is there a way that this can be converted to specify specific STATUS values.
Say I only wanted 10 of the 72 possible values.  Is this possible?

Comment: @user2167023 it looks like you've replied with multiple answers. Please delete those answers and instead reply with comments on this answer and / or updates to your post. If you only need 10 specific values, then just filter them with a `WHERE` clause inside the first CTE `_Table2Sorted`, for example `WHERE [STATUS] IN (214, 217, 605, ...)`. If you only want 10 columns shown too, then you'd only need to list `Status#` columns 1 through 10 in the places my comments mention adjusting the number of columns.

Comment: @user2167023 To your other question / details in your accidental answer, if you need the same `STATUS` values to always be in the same columns, then please update your post with which statuses map to which numbered columns, and provide an example please.

Comment: Sorry about that... this forum is a bit different that others I have been on....

Comment: I am doing this now... I added a WHERE clause to limit the search...  But its showing the returns all mixed up in the fields.... I didnt realize that when I originally posted.

Comment: @user2167023 No problem. Can you please add an example of what you're expecting in your original post? Please also provide the list of the 10 `STATUS` values and the order you want them displayed in. I should be able to update my answer accordingly once I know that information.