# Merging multiple rows into one in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have the following table :

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Account |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three | Data1 | Acc1 |
| One | Two | Three | Data2 | Acc2 |
| One | Two | Three | Data3 | Acc3 |
| Five | Six | Seven | Data3 | Acc4 |
| Five | Six | Seven | Data1 | Acc1 |

And I would like to make a query to obtain the following result :

| Column 1 | Column2 | Column3 | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three | Acc1 | Acc2 | Acc3 |
| Five | Six | Seven | Acc1 | NULL | Acc4 |

I tried something like :

```
select Column1, Column2, Column3,
case
    when Column4 = 'Data1' then Account
end as Data1,
case
    when Column4 = 'Data2' then Account
end as Data2,
case
    when Column4 = 'Data3' then Account
end as Data3
from mytable group by Column1, Column2, Column3
```

But instead I got the following :

| Column 1 | Column2 | Column3 | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three | Acc1 | NULL | NULL |
| Five | Six | Seven | NULL | NULL | Acc4 |

It seems that `group by` stops at the first distinct line, therefore it stops reading lines with `One, Two Three` once it found one, and of course same with `Five, Six, Seven`, therefore it only fills the `Data` columns according to the first match.

How can I get to my desired behaviour ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See tag [pivot].

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table table
(
Column1 varchar(20),
Column2 varchar(20),
Column3 varchar(20),
Column4 varchar(20),
Account varchar(20)
);

insert into @table
values('One','Two','Three','Data1','Acc1'),
('One','Two','Three','Data2','Acc2'),
('One','Two','Three','Data3','Acc3'),
('Five','Six','Seven','Data3','Acc4'),
('Five','Six','Seven','Data1','Acc1');

select * from @table PIVOT  
(  
  max(Account)  
  FOR Column4 IN ([Data1], [Data2], [Data3])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a PIVOT function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You do not get the expected result because you should use conditional aggregation.

```
select Column1,
       Column2,
       Column3,
       max(case when Column4 ='Data1' then Account else null end)  as Data1,
       max(case when Column4 ='Data2' then Account else null end)  as Data2,
       max(case when Column4 ='Data3' then Account else null end)  as Data3
from test
group by Column1,Column2,Column3
```

Above query takes in consideration only the values Data1,Data2 and Data3 in Column4.

If you want to do this dynamically you could use prepared statement:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; #this is because of group_concat default max value 

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('max(case when Column4 = ''',Column4,''' 
                                          then Account end) ', Column4)) INTO @sql 
FROM
  test;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3 ,', @sql, ' 
                  FROM test 
                   GROUP BY Column1,Column2,Column3');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/ipsHlnQm

There are plenty of examples in this site or others about MySQL pivot, below some links:

[MySQL single table static and dynamic pivot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27659/mysql-single-table-static-and-dynamic-pivot)

https://ubiq.co/database-blog/how-to-create-dynamic-pivot-tables-in-mysql/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I guess because it is an aggregation it does not stop at the first match, is it correct ?